# IIS rewriting url

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I can't figure out how to solve this problem with url rewriting:

urls following this pattern

app/(.*)

should be redirected to app/index.cshtml

However the app folder contains resources such as sub-folders, js files and html files. These should be ignored an no redirection should be done.

Here's how Ive done it :

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="app/(.*/.js)" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rule 2">
      <match url="app/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app/index.cshtml" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I've only tried to exclude js files for now, but when I browse to app/someurl, I get an error because one of the js files cannot be loaded. I think that's because the first rule does not work.

Can you help ?

Comment: Under what condition(s) should the redirect be ignored? only when in sub-folders AND requesting js files OR html files?

Comment: redirection should be ignored when requesting js files and html files  inside the app folder as well as in sub-folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing :

```
<rule name="Rule1">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.jpg$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.gif$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.png$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.css$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.ico$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.cur$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.js$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.xml$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.svg$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.ttf$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.eot$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.woff$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.html$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app/index.cshtml" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Pretty sure if you keep only the 2 first conditions it should work as you expect it.