# IIS Url Rewrite: how to ignore minified javascript and css

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Using the following rule, I can successfully rewrite urls to redirect to app/index.cshtml. Som resources like images, css and javascripts should not be redirected, so I've used conditions:

```
 <rule name="AngularJS">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.png$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.css$" />>
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.js$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app/index.cshtml" />
    </rule>
```

But as soon as I start using minified content, the requested URL becomes similar to :

/myapp/bundles/utilities?v=EH9YuZDBt_fj7iqRP2QA8lCkJ59wjV6woELIwvR7irk1

How do I prevent that type of url to be redirected  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS rewriting url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195698/iis-rewriting-url)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a ignore rule, match URLs to ignore

```
<rule name="Ignore" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(images|css|bundles).*"/>
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"/>
   <action type="None"/>
</rule>
```